# How to query a story based on `iteration id`

Tags: iteration

[https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/HierarchicalRequirement?query=(Iteration.ref contains "10478614337")&fetch=true](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/HierarchicalRequirement?query=%28Iteration.ref%20contains%20%2210478614337%22%29&fetch=true)

I am trying to query a story based on the `iteration ID` (see above URL), but the message says

> Could not parse: Could not traverse to "ref" on type Iteration in the query segment "Iteration.ref""

Do you have any advice?

Comment: What language or system is this to do with? Where is the code you have tried which is giving you the error?

Comment: i just put the url on the address editbox of IE, then I got the error.

While, the expected result can be return with the Iterantion.Name query like below:
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/HierarchicalRequirement?query=(Iteration.Name contains "Iter 03,CDD 6.1")&fetch=true

Comment: Presumably this is some website's API, though? Do you have documentation for it? Is it using a standard CMS system that someone here might know about? As it stands, there's little chance of anyone being able to answer your question.

Comment: Also, the URLs you've given ask for a username and password when I try to access them.

Answer (score 0):

i was fowarded to stackoverflow from Rally developper portal.

I suppose that there are experts here specific to the development of Rally.